# Sql Server Reporting Services: How to insert a subtotal row when group change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

i've a sql query i transpose to a tablix matrix. 
My tablix is :

```
Group,  Year,  January,  Febr,   March.... December
 A1     2010     20       30      15 .....
 A1     2011     3        18      ........ 
 A2     2010     8        7
 A3     2010     8        9
 A3     2011
```

I need a summary Row under the end of each group (A1, A2, A3) with the delta of the rows.
I don't know how to summarize in Reporting Services (2005). 
For instance:

```
A1 2010
A1 2011
 Delta         17 (20-3) ... 12 (30-18) ...
A2 2010
 Delta  ....
A3 2010
A3 2011
 Delta  ....
```

This is the actual table: 
[image]

In red, the row where i have to place the expression ... 
For total, i intend the differnce percentage.

Can you please help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to reference the group name in the expression:

```
=SUM(Fields!FieldName.Value, "GroupName")
```